# Cannot solve equation

Tags: equation-solving

I just started using mathematica and I'm facing a problem that I just can't solve. I want to solve the following equation:
[image]

Code:

```
eqn = {(ao)/((c*Exp[a*(n - o)/n]) (-Log[(c*Exp[a*(n - o)/n])] + Log[c] + a)^2) == m, 
       ao*1/2 < n};

Solve[eqn, n, Reals]
```

Program says ' This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.'

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This equation is highly nonlinear equation. you may use FindRoot but you need to provide numerical values to other variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I tried using FindRoot but didn't succeed.

Comment: You may start by something like this `r = Reduce[eqn[[1]] /. a*(n - o)/n -> x /. {n -> (a o)/(a - x)}, x, 
  Reals]; FullSimplify[r /. x -> a*(n - o)/n, 
 Assumptions -> ao*1/2 < n]`

Comment: If you give specific values for the parameters `ao`, `a`, etc. then it becomes amenable to `Solve`.

Comment: @Daniel: Is that so?! Thx, I will try that.

Comment: [Caveat: I made a "variable" out of `Exp[a*(n - o)/n]` and solved for that. Depending on how smart `Solve` is, you may or may not need to massage by hand like I did.]

Answer (score 2):

If you use FindRoot you can get some solutions. I don't know what range of values that you are expecting but I will assume some.

```
eq = (ao)/((c*
      Exp[a*(n - o)/n]) (-Log[(c*Exp[a*(n - o)/n])] + Log[c] + a)^2)
Plot[{eq /. {a -> 1, c -> 1, o -> 1, ao -> 1}, 20}, {n, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

for this set of values you will have two roots. you can find them as follows:

```
    FindRoot[(eq /. {a -> 1, c -> 1, o -> 1, ao -> 1}) == 20, {n, 2}]
   (* {n -> 6.85462} *)

    FindRoot[(eq /. {a -> 1, c -> 1, o -> 1, ao -> 1}) == 20, {n, .2}]
   (* {n -> 0.121873} *)
```

Comment: Looks good! Although, I was hoping to create a universal solution without using values.

Comment: This is why i added the term (ao)/2 < n. This is the inflection point, so I'm just looking on the right part of the function with only one solution for n.

Comment: @Andy as I said, the equation is highly nonlinear with multi variables. I don't think you can find a universal solution to the problem. you can get bunch of solutions and then use regression analysis to find empirical relationship.